# displaying multiple datatypes from a custom class in a recyclerview

Tags: java, android

So I am working on an android studio project using java where we store a collection of information about an item in a custom class called Items (for example a String name, and a double cost) and we need to have a display page that displays each of those datatypes of the item in the same row but separated. So for instance it should show the name of the item, and then the cost of the item.

For our purposes it seems we should use a recyclerview, but I'm not entirely sure how to make this work. So what should I do?

Comment: Hi Austin, you need to be more specific about your problem. If you don't know how to create a recycler view, you can start by checking this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

First, to use the RecyclerView you should add the support library in your app level build.gradle file like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Then add the Recycler View to your layout like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Now that you have done this, you can follow the documentation by Android Developers to see how to write the Java code to inflate your Recycler View with elements and set an adapter on it. 
[This is the link.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java)

Basically what you have to do is create an Adapter class that `extends RecyclerView.Adapter`. Then, you have to create a class that can take the datatypes you mentioned, such as the cost and other data. Finally, in your Activity you will pass in your data to a list of the class you created. Then, you will pass in that list to your RecyclerView adapter and you should be able to view the results. All of these steps can be found in detail at [the link here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java)

I hope this answer helped you!